# How to update rendered flat/section list items immediately React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-state-management

I am creating a `ContactListScreen`. The immediate child of `ContactListScreen` is `ContactItems` and `ContactItems` is a sectionList which renders each `ContactItem`.
But the problem arises, as my `ContactItems` should be multi-selectable.

I passed the array of `selectedContacts` from my state to every `ContactItem`. The logic here I used is `ContactItem` checks if the length of `selectedContacts` is 0 or not. If the length is zero it should not render any `selectItemView`, if I select an item, it should push itself to the `selectedContacts` using a callback. But the problem is the children components (`ContactItem`)s doesn't get updated until I selected deselect an item twice or thrice. How can I make it work?

Part of **ContactList.tsx**

```js
class ContactList extends Component {
    this.state = {
            loading: false,
            error: null,
            data: [],
            selectedItems: []
        };

    handleSelectionPress = (item) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const { selectedItems } = prevState;
            const isSelected = selectedItems.includes(item);
            return {
                selectedItems: isSelected
                    ? selectedItems.filter(title => title !== item)
                    : [item, ...selectedItems],
            };
        });
    };

    renderItem(item: any) {
        return <ContactItem item={item.item}
                isSelected={this.state.selectedItems.includes(item.item)}
                onPress={this.handleSelectionPress}
                selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
               />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SectionList
                    sections={this.state.data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => (
                        section.data.length > 0 ?
                            <Text>
                                {section.title}
                            </Text> : (null)
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Part of ContactItem.tsx

```js
class ContactItem extend Component {
     render() {
        const checkBox = <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            this.props.onPress(this.props.item)
        }
        } style={this.props.selectedItems.length > 0 && {display: 'none'}}>
            {!this.props.isSelected ?
                <View style={{borderRadius: 10, height: 20, width: 20, borderColor: "#f0f", borderWidth: 1}}>
                </View> : <View style={{
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    borderColor: "#f0f",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    backgroundColor: "#f0f"
                }}>
                </View>}

        </TouchableOpacity>
        return (
            <View style={this.styles.contactsContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onLongPress={() => this.props.onPress(this.props.item)}>
                    <View style={this.styles.contactInfo}>
                        {checkBox}
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
}
```

Note: Functional Components are not used where I work.

Comment: Please provide some code for better understanding.

Comment: Added some of the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain about this, but I have a feeling that the problem is that the `SectionList` component isn't triggering its update because the supplied `sections={this.state.data}` property never changes.

The easiest way to handle this is to add the `selectedItems` as an [extraData](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#extradata) property to section list:

```
 <SectionList
     sections={this.state.data}
     extraData={this.state.selectedItems}
     //...
```